# How to use IDTECH sdk in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, payment-gateway, air-native-extension

I have a IDTECH .xcproj with me and some amateur documentation with it. I have no idea how to use those classes with my cocoa library. I have implemented its .jar in my android app.

Comment: Why didn't IDTECH provide you with instructions?  http://www.idtechproducts.com/support/daq/general-product-support.html

Comment: I want to add that i have a unimag card reader from IDTECH which helps in card swiping on different devices.

Comment: ...So their SDK didn't come with a manual?

Comment: As first we only used it for android a long way back, at that time we were perfectly guided. Now i want to integrate it on iOS platform but the documentation is not that helpfull.

Comment: IDTECH is going to be the best source of information for this.

Comment: I got it but i could not find it that helpfull may b so i posted for help. If you can please help me out.

Comment: Unless someone from IDTECH happens to wander in here and stumble over your question (which seems very unlikely), I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot atleast for taking time and commenting the question found that i am of my own now :).

Comment: @JaySampat did u added the IDTECH for ios?